# Typescript Types are recognized only when the respective type files ( *.d.ts ) are kept opened. How to auto recognize these type files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

In my Gatsby typescript project, the types defined in the "*.d.ts" files are always unrecognized and is always highlighted as an unknown type.

But when the respective type file is opened in a new tab, the respective lint errors are abscent.

How to make sure VS CODE auto scans and identifies type files in the project folder without having to open them manually everytime ?

Given below is the `tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Folder structure]

[image: Chord.d.ts]

[image: Chord.ts]

Comment: Where are your `d.ts` files located?

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla Some are on the root folder level. And few other type files are under different folders under same project, but have been used in different parts of the application.

Comment: Did you write them yourself? Normally type definitions are located in a root folder named `@types` containing a sub folder for each module the definitions belong to.

Comment: Yes. These are custom type files. In the above example, one such type file is "Chord.d.ts".

Comment: Is "Chord" a JavaScript module/package or what is it?

Comment: Chord is actually a ts file named as "Chord.ts". It contains a class. And the respective types file is "Chord.d.ts". Both files are under same folder. But, i tend to reuse these Types in other places too. Thats where the issue is. Is there a way to say typescript to scan the whole project root folder and get to know all the available types or is this a vs code config issue ?

Comment: I still struggle a bit to understand your use case. If Chord is a TS file why do you need a Chord.d.ts file? TS files contain the types. d.ts files are only needed for JS code that has no type information.

Comment: Ive added more screenshots to clear the confusion. I have used a separate file ( chord.d.ts ) to maintain the types for "Chord.ts" file which contains only Chord class. Is this correct or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Use the `include` and `exclude` options in the tsconfig, and also make sure to look at `typeRoots` and the `types` compiler options. [Example of include/exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#tsconfig-bases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put everything related to the `Chord` class into the `Chord.ts` file. `d.ts` files are used to define types for JavaScript modules which is not what you have here.

In your `index.tsx` file you can then import the `Shapes` type like so:

```
import { Shapes } from "Chord";
```

Of course every type that you import must be exported in your `Chord.ts` file.